# How do you go about finding a 12 digit prime number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers

How do you go about finding a 12 digit prime number?

Comment: Please could you add a bit more context? Do you want us to give you a 12 digit prime number? Are you looking for a general method for generating a large prime number, and 12 digits just so happens to be large enough? Do you know any number theory - how in depth can our answers be?

Comment: By writing it in [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+12+digit+prime+number).

Comment: I am looking for a general method. The question just wants to know how to go about finding one.

Comment: What makes this problem interesting to you? I mean why $12$?

Answer (score 2):

100 000 000 003 is one. 100 000 000 019 is another.

If you want an algorithm, you can look at number sieves (or this [general article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) on generating prime numbers).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to repeatedly generate a random 12-digit number then test it for primality.  Fortunately, there is a deterministic procedure to test primality that has been proven to work for all primes $p < 341,550,071,728,321$, see [this useful site](http://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove2_3.html).

Comment: The prime counting function for $10^12$ is 37607912018, and for $10^11$ is 4118054813, so if you generate uniformly and independently 12 digit numbers, you have about a 3.7% chance of getting a prime each time (so the amount of time you have to wait to get a prime follows a Geometric(0.037) distribution, so about 27 numbers generated on average).

Comment: @Batman: Although you can speed that up by only looking at odds (or more generally W-tricking the numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Another nice example is $p=2^{39}-7$. It is equal to $549.755.813.881$, which has $12$ digits. And indeed $p$ is prime.

Comment: By easy you mean it's possible to see it without computers?

Comment: @Ant: I have deleted the "easy" part.

Comment: Are there some special theorems to attack this just as with Mersenne primes?

Answer (score 0):

With [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/):

```
randomprime(10^11, 10^12)
```

which [you can see](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=pari.git;a=blob;f=src/basemath/prime.c#l975) is just generating and testing random numbers in the appropriate range.